# docker best way to run mysql

Tags: mysql, database, docker, containers

I'm new in docker, and i have two microservices running in two containers and i would like to create simple database for them.
i created it like that:

```
docker run --net=kajsnetwork -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='mypassword' -v /storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

i enter the container using

```
docker exec -it containernumber /bin/bash
```

and then i created database... But when i went to /var/lib/mysql mysql on host i haven't there nothing new - no database which i created from docker file. Did i something wrong ?

I would like to have database with data stored on host, but running in a docker container (is it good solution?) ? How to do it correctly?

Comment: I think all you need to do is to swap volumes. First path is from host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker cmd option `-v /storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir:/var/lib/mysql` indicates that you are mounting **host** directory `/storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir` to `/var/lib/mysql` as a **data volume of the container**.

So if you check `/var/lib/mysql` from the **container** your should see the same contents as `/storage/mysql1/mysql-datadir` in your **host** machine.

More details:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to docker exec to create an instance: the container should already have one.

The doc mentions:

> The `-v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql` part of the command mounts the `/my/own/datadir` directory **from the underlying host system** as `/var/lib/mysql` inside the container, where MySQL by default will write its data files.

So the order matters.